# send aiohttp post request with headers through proxy connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, aiohttp

What I have now (Python 3.4):

```
r = yield from aiohttp.request('post', URL, params=None, data=values, headers=headers)
```

What is in the [documentation](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/client.html#proxy-support):

```
conn = aiohttp.ProxyConnector(proxy="http://some.proxy.com")
r = await aiohttp.get('http://python.org', connector=conn)
```

So, how should I send a post request with headers through proxy connection with aiohttp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
connector = aiohttp.ProxyConnector(proxy="http://some.proxy.com")
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector)
async with session.post("http://example.com/post", data=b"binary data") as resp:
    print(resp.status)

session.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
import aiohttp

conn = aiohttp.ProxyConnector(proxy="http://some.proxy.com")

r = await aiohttp.post('http://python.org', connector=conn, data=b"hello", headers={})
```

or

```
import aiohttp

from aiohttp import request

conn = aiohttp.ProxyConnector(proxy="http://some.proxy.com")

r = await request('post','http://python.org', connector=conn, data=b"hello", headers={})
```

Comment: Using bare `request()`, `get()` and family is deprecated since aiohttp 0.21.0.
`ClientSession` is the only recommended way to perform client requests.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov :   

def get(url, **kwargs):
    warnings.warn("Use ClientSession().get() instead", DeprecationWarning)
    return request(hdrs.METH_GET, url, **kwargs)

this is what is written in 0.21.0 branch of aiohttp.

I agree that they are planning to remove normal get, put, post and clientSession is recommended way to go. thanks

Comment: Just to be clear -- I'm the aiohttp maintainer, it was mine change :)